# How to investigate a release bundle crashing?

Tags: react-native

My app works like a charm in Debug mode on both Android and iOS, building from both MacOS and Windows but release builds (for both platforms from both OS) crash at launch.

From both XCode console and adb logcat, I get the following error: `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'n.apply')`

Given the way it behaves, it really seems the release JS bundle has an error (maybe a third-party lib not supporting the latest version of RN in release mode?) but how can I investigate it?

FYI: I'm on RN 0.61.1.